# How can I draw boxes in C# when the position moves top-left to the initial position?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, drawing

So I'm trying to allow the user to draw boxes on a form and all goes well when I draw from top left to bottom right.  Once either the X or Y position become less than the original it stops drawing and the rectangle is gone.

I've made some changes to the paint method to try to adjust its position and sort of move it to where it should be to simulate this behavior but it just not working correctly.  Is there a better way to go about this?  I can get multiple rectangles on the screen and even double click to detect and remove them.  I just can't get them to draw in any other direction besides bottom-right

```
    // All rectangles saved to the form
    private List<Rectangle> rects;

    // Current rectangle if one is being drawn
    private Rectangle tempRect;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rects = new List<Rectangle>();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        tempRect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            int tempX = tempRect.X;
            int tempY = tempRect.Y;
            int tempWidth = tempRect.Width;
            int tempHeight = tempRect.Height;

            if (e.X < tempRect.Location.X)
            {
                tempX = e.X;
                tempWidth = tempRect.Width + (tempRect.Location.X - e.X);
            }
            else
                tempWidth = e.X - tempRect.Location.X;

            if (e.Y < tempRect.Location.Y)
            {
                tempY = e.Y;
                tempHeight = tempRect.Height + (tempRect.Location.Y - e.Y);
            }
            else
                tempHeight = e.Y - tempRect.Location.Y;

            Point rectLocation = new Point(tempX, tempY);
            Size rectSize = new Size(tempWidth, tempHeight);

            tempRect = new Rectangle(rectLocation, rectSize);
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Must be within constraint, prevents tiny invisible rectangles from being added
        if (tempRect.Width >= 10 && tempRect.Height >= 10)
            rects.Add(tempRect);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
        {
            // Redraws all existing rectangles onto the form
            foreach (Rectangle rect in rects)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);

            // Must be within constraint, prevents tiny invisible rectangles from being added
            if (tempRect.Width >= 10 && tempRect.Height >= 10)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, tempRect);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code significantly. Instead of creating a `tempRect` when mouse is down, you can create `tempStartPoint`. This way, you will not need that many manipulations in the `MouseMove` event handler, all the code will boil down to one statement:

```
tempRect =
    new Rectangle(
        Math.Min(tempStartPoint.X, tempEndPoint.X),
        Math.Min(tempStartPoint.Y, tempEndPoint.Y),
        Math.Abs(tempStartPoint.X - tempEndPoint.X),
        Math.Abs(tempStartPoint.Y - tempEndPoint.Y));
```

Full code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly List<Rectangle> rects = new List<Rectangle>();
    private Point tempStartPoint;
    private Rectangle tempRect;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        tempStartPoint = e.Location;
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
            return;
        Point tempEndPoint = e.Location;
        tempRect =
            new Rectangle(
                Math.Min(tempStartPoint.X, tempEndPoint.X),
                Math.Min(tempStartPoint.Y, tempEndPoint.Y),
                Math.Abs(tempStartPoint.X - tempEndPoint.X),
                Math.Abs(tempStartPoint.Y - tempEndPoint.Y));
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Must be within constraint, prevents tiny invisible rectangles from being added
        if (tempRect.Width >= 10 && tempRect.Height >= 10)
            rects.Add(tempRect);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
        {
            // Redraws all existing rectangles onto the form
            foreach (Rectangle rect in rects)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);

            // Must be within constraint, prevents tiny invisible rectangles from being added
            if (tempRect.Width >= 10 && tempRect.Height >= 10)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, tempRect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much easier to read too, not sure where my bug was but this breaking it down like this makes it much easier to maintain and all works like a charm :)